# Determine if the following series converges or diverges.

Tags: complex-analysis, summation

I'm struggling with this series. Could you try to help me me?

> Determine if the following series converges or diverges.$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^n$$
>   I think that I have to use Abel's test and I know the convergence of the first part of the equation. But I don't know how to deal with the second.

Comment: What do you call "the first part of the equation" and "the second"?

Comment: Indeed $\sum w^n/\sqrt n$ converges for all $w\ne1$ with $|w|=1$ by Dirichlet's test.

Comment: @Michael Lee: Why won't Abel's test apply?

Comment: Very nice. As $\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2} = (-1)^{1/3}$, we have $$\sum_{n=1}^N \left(\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^n = \sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^{n/3} = \sum_{n=1}^{N\bmod 6} (-1)^{n/3}$$ which is clearly bounded.

Comment: Actually, yes, Abel's test will apply. My bad. Abel's test, in complex analysis, states that for $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 0$, the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nz^n$$ converges everywhere on $\mathbb{D}\setminus \{1\}$. As $\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ lies in the closed unit disk and $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, we have that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^n$$ must converge.

Comment: You can use Abel criterion since the general term of the series is $\frac{e^{in\frac{\pi}{3}}}{\sqrt{n}}$

Answer (score 0):

First note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{1+i\sqrt 3}{2}\right)^n&=\left(\cos(\pi/3)+i\sin(\pi/3)\right)^n\\\\
&=\cos(n\pi/3)+i\sin(n\pi/3)
\end{align}$$

Next, we can write

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\left(\frac{1+i\sqrt 3}{2}\right)^n}{\sqrt n}=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\cos(n\pi/3)}{\sqrt n}+i\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sin(n\pi/3)}{\sqrt n}$$

Note that $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ goes to zeo monotonically as $n\to \infty$ and that the partial sums, $\sum_{n=1}^N \cos(n\pi/3)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^N \sin(n\pi/3)$, are bounded as

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^N \cos(n\pi/3)\right|=\left|\sin\left((2N+1)\pi/6 \right)-\frac12\right|\le \frac32$$

and

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^N \cos(n\pi/3)\right|=\left|\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}-\cos\left((2N+1)\pi/6 \right)\right|\le \frac{\sqrt 3}2+1$$

Hence, [Dirichlet's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test#Statement) guarantees that both series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(n\pi/3)}{\sqrt n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n\pi/3)}{\sqrt n}$ converge.

> Therefore, the series of interest convereges.

Answer (score 0):

*Abel's test*

Be $\,x\in\mathbb{R}\,$ with $\,\displaystyle\frac{x}{2\pi}\notin \mathbb{Z}\,$ .

$\displaystyle |\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{ixn}}{\sqrt{n}}|= \frac{1}{|1-e^{ix}|}|e^{ix}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty e^{ix(n+1)}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}})|$

$\displaystyle\hspace{2cm}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2-2\cos x}}\left(1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}})\right)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{1-\cos x}}$

$\displaystyle \left(\frac{e^{ixn}}{\sqrt{n}}\right)_n\,$ is a null sequence therefore the (limited) series (above) is convergent.

With $\,\displaystyle x:=\frac{\pi}{3}\,$ and $\,\displaystyle e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}=\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\,$ we get $\,\displaystyle |\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^n}{\sqrt{n}}|\leq 2 \,$ .